# Simplify the PATCH

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have to PATCH my entity to update some chosen field.

I wrote the following code that the user in the payload can type the fields he wants to update, but it is not necessary to update them all as PUT does:

```
public ResponseItemDTO patch(Long id, RequestAtualizaItemDTO requestItemDTO) {
        Item item = repositoryItem.findById(id)
                .orElseThrow(PedidoNaoEncontradoException::new);

        if(requestItemDTO.getName() != null) {
            item.setName(requestItemDTO.getName());
        }
        if(requestItemDTO.getValor() != null) {
            item.setValor(requestItemDTO.getValor());
        }
        if(requestItemDTO.getDesc() != null) {
            item.setDesc(requestItemDTO.getDesc());
        }
        if(requestItemDTO.getOffer() != null) {
            item.setOffer(requestItemDTO.getOffer());
        }
        repositoryItem.save(item);
        return modelMapper.map(item, ResponseItemDTO.class);
    }
```

My question is if there is a more simplified way to make the patch without the need for IF?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, I hear you on this. My approach in the past, on some projects, has been to just create a "patcher utility" that's reusable and buries the if/else-ing somewhere else...It uses functional consumers to apply the change if required.

Here's a sample with two types; you can add support for types as necessary.

```
public final class Patcher {

    public static void patchInt(Integer value, IntConsumer consumer) {
        if (value != null) {
            consumer.accept(value);
        }
    }

    public static void patchString(String value, Consumer<String> consumer) {
        if (value != null) {
            consumer.accept(orNull(value));
        }
    }

    /* I'm using apache commons lang StringUtils but use whatever you want**/
    public static String orNull(String value) {
        if (StringUtils.isBlank(value)) {
            return null;
        }
        return value;
    }

}
```

Then, you can use it like this..

```
Patcher.patchInt(requestBody.intValue(), dbEntity::setIntValue);
Patcher.patchString(requestBody.stringValue(), dbEntity::setStringValue);
```